# Catalog price rule - Original price vs. new in order backend?

Tags: price, backend, catalog-price-rules, discount

I have set a catalog price rule that gives 30% off on all products. Everything works fine, but I would like to see the normal price in backend when looking at an order.

Is this a missing functionality that needs custom modding or have I somehow messed something up in settings or with my custom modifications?

Preferably it should be in the order item list next to price, original price etc. - in my mind original price would be the price before catalog rules, but I guess that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a missing functionality. For the catalog price rule it only shows you the discounted price in the orders. Depending on your needs you could change that again and let it calculate the original price in your orders but I´m not sure if you need that.